# dell power edge t410 HDD not showing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, centos

i have purchased dell poweredge t410 in seconds 
previously in that pc installed centos now i am trying to install win server 2008
after booting windows its showing no HardDisk is available.

how can i install windows now please suggest me if any setting is der in bios.

Comment: Are you trying to install them together or are you trying to overwrite the CentOS installation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the RAID drivers during the install. You can get them at support.dell.com and searching for the T410 drivers.